what is the mistake of my thought process in the minJumps problem?
the problem was about the min number of jumps to get to the end of the array.
My logic was to loop over the array through element until i+arr[i]<n-1.
in this while loop I do a for loop for elements and try to figure out the max in the range of the value of the element. Then I update i to have the index of this maxValue.
public static int minJumps(int[] arr){
            // your code here
            if(arr.length==1){
                return -1;
            }
            int jumps=1;
            int maxIndex=0;

            int i=0;

            while(i+arr[i]<arr.length-1){
                if(arr[i]==0){
                    return -1;
                }
                int max=0;
                for(int j=i+1;j<=arr[i]+i;j++){

                    if(arr[j]>=max){
                        max=arr[j];
                        maxIndex=j;
                    }

                }


                i=maxIndex;





                jumps++;


            }
            return jumps;

        }


Please provide the exact challenge. It is not clear what a jump is, and what we should imagine with "to get to".

Given an array of N integers arr[] where each element represents the maximum length of the jump that can be made forward from that element. This means if arr[i] = x, then we can jump any distance y such that y ≤ x.
Find the minimum number of jumps to reach the end of the array (starting from the first element). If an element is 0, then you cannot move through that element.
Note: Return -1 if you can't reach the end of the array.

Gargouri, when asked for clarification it's best to edit your question to  address the question, rather than elaborating in a comment. Questions should be stand-alone, in part because not all readers read all comments. Questions should always begin with a statement of the question in words, then one or more examples should be provided when that would help readers understand the question. When examples are provided always include the desired result.

There are a few issues in your attempt:

When the input array has size 1, then you are already at the end of the array, and should return 0, not -1.

Your algorithm assumes that it is always best to make the jump to an element that has the greatest value, but this is not always true. Consider input array {4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0}. At index 0 the correct jump to make is to index 4, not to index 1, yet your algorithm will choose index 1 and get at a 0 one step later and will return -1. But it should return 2.


So you'll have to think of a different algorithm. One way is to use the principle of dynamic programming: keep track of how many jumps are needed for when you start at the right of the array. Of course, from the very last element we know it is 0, from the one-but-last element we should check if we can jump to the last or not, and so we could go backwards. We would always know what the best results were for all the next spots in the array, and so we can compare those and choose the best (much like what you did, but this time with the right values). When you've reached index 0, you'll have the answer there.
If you cannot make it, here is a spoiler implementation of that idea:

     public static int minJumps(int[] arr) {
         int n = arr.length;
         int[] distance = new int[n]; // Dynamic programming tabulation area
         distance[n-1] = 0; // Arrival spot, so number of steps from there is 0
         for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
             int minDistance = n;
             // Find best jump: we already know the least jumps from further spots
             for (int j = Math.min(i + arr[i], n-1); j > i; j--) {
                 minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distance[j]);
             }
             distance[i] = minDistance + 1;
         }
         return distance[0];
     }


Spoiler comment, so cover your eyes if you don't want to read it: The recurrence relation is J(n) = min{sϵS(n)}J(s)+1, where J(n) is the minimum number of steps to reach the nth stone, S(n) is the set of stones s < n that can reach stone n in one jump.  The recurrence relation therefore reads, "The minimum number of jumps to reach stone n is obtained by minimizing, over all preceding stones s from which stone n can be reached in a single jump, the quantity J(s) + 1.
